# UITableViewCell separators based on array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a JSON array called `contacts` containing around 100 contacts.
Now I want to copy the functionality of the `contacts.app` by showing a letter section title for each letter in the alphabet on the right.

I've tried several things but I'm wondering what would be the most memory efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Basically add an header for each letter and below each section add your corresponding rows no ?

Comment: Could you tell us what you tried? This is actually a very simple thing to do and I'm not sure where you are struggling. Here is a tutorial about implementing a section index list (the letter bar on the right), which might help you: https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/. The rest is just splitting your array into contacts starting with letter a, then letter b, etc. and populating the sections in your UITableViewDataSource implementation.

Comment: Oh and it's called sections or sections headers, not separators. Separators are the thin lines between each cell in the table view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this two methods

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

```
        let sectionHeader = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 40))

        let lblTitle:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: tableView.frame.size.width-20, height: 21))
        var strTitle : String!
        switch section {
        case 0:
            strTitle = "A"
            break
        case 1:
            strTitle = "B"
            break
        case 2:
            strTitle = "C"
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        lblTitle.text = strTitle
        sectionHeader.addSubview(lblTitle)

        return sectionHeader
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
   return 40
}
```

Here I set Alphabets in switch case statement for Understanding purpose. You can Fetch this alphabet from Dictionary or Array Or Json Response according to your requirement.

It is general or Efficient solution. I hope it will help you.

Comment: How can I do this automated? So I have the array `contacts` of which I want to create these headers.